# How to attach a object to a dynamically added element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Bootstrap 4 `popover` like so:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'hover'
});
```

But now in jquery, I'm dynamically adding an element.

```
var leaveUser = $('.popover').clone().prependTo('.new-popups');
```

But the `.popover()` is not taking affect for this new dynamicly added element.
How do I get it to work?

Comment: did you tried using it's parent container in the selector like [$('.container  [data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'hover'
});]

Comment: @Bilel No, but what difference would that make? It is still binding to the same elements will not bind to new ones.

Comment: did you tried ? :)

Comment: Dynamically added elements in jQuery in any  situation by append() clone() appendto() prepend().... They could be targeted using their parent (dom available) container. Unless the popover library is adding an exception. This is why I asked you if you tried :)

Comment: @Bilel okay, well my problem is solved, thanks to George answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'hover'
});
```

Will only match elements that are currently in the DOM, which your clone is not.

You will need to either use this selection and method *after* cloning, or call the method explicitely on your new element after cloning it:

```
var leaveUser = $('.popover')
    .clone()
    .prependTo('.new-popups')
    .popover({
        trigger: 'hover'
    });
```

Comment: Of course! My clone would never get that, thanks! let me try your suggestion.